# What is difference between Long object and primitive type long in Java?

Tags: java, long-integer

I thought long and Long class are more or less same thing.
I saw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16720992/1391249)

When I displayed `Long.MAX_VALUE` it displayed `9223372036854775807`. 
But when I was doing multiplication of `1000000*1000000` which is `10^12` ; it gave overflow.

I was using long data type to store value...and while debugging it had value `-727379968` after multiplication

Where am I making mistake or I am totally dumb?

---

Update: This was my code, and I got my mistake as specified in answer.

```
 
 for (;;)
    ppltn[i] = Integer.parseInt(tk.nextToken());
```

`for (int i = 0; i < noc; i++)  //sum is of long type
    sum = sum + min * ppltn[i];  //min and ppltn are of integer type`

Comment: Just because it's a long doesn't mean it can't overflow.

Comment: I know it would if value is greater than "9223372036854775807"
but not for 10^12

Comment: I don't know where, but I'm making some silly-silly silly mistake ...

Comment: Let's see how you actually did it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression

```
1000000 * 1000000;
```

is integer multiplication as both operands are integers. Therefore you are limited by the max value of an integer.

You need to do long multiplication

```
1000000L * 1000000 /* L if you want it*/;
```

where at least one operand is a `long` and the other gets promoted to a `long` (if it isn't already).

Answer (score 2):

In Java, `^` doesn't mean "power".  It is a bitwise XOR operator.

therefore 10^6 means 10 XOR 6 instead 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10

---

it is hard to guess without seeing your code.

However my guess is you are doing somehting like

```
long l = 1000000 * 10000000;
```

If so, here is the problem.

literal `1000000` is in fact an `int` instead of `long`, and therefore, `1000000 * 10000000` is doing a `int` multiplication and it got overflow (max of `int` is something around 2,xxx,xxx,xxx).  The "overflowed" value is then cast to a long.  Which give you the "strange" result.

Comment: Where's the overflow in that?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis what do you mean? there is nothing as "overflow" for XOR

Comment: I want your answer to explain `But when I was doing multiplication of 10^6*10^6 which is 10^12 and it gave overflow.`

Comment: I'm sorry it's 1000000*1000000

Comment: I think you should be clear on the question.  It do make me think that you are having `10^6` as the expression.  See my update then

Comment: While I agree with the overflow synopsis, 8,xxx,xxx (~8 million) is not even close for an integer limit! 2^32 is ~4 billion, 2^31-1 (the maximum int value) is ~2 billion.

Comment: stupid me, some problem when hitting the calculator  lol.  Yes, 2,xxx,xxx,xxx is the max of `int`.  It IS already an overflow for your 1,000,000 * 1,000,000 result anyway.