# Getting a date from the next Alarm

Tags: java, android, date, time, alarm

I've been trying to turn the result of

```
AlarmManager m = (AlarmManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
String next=m.getNextAlarmClock().getTriggerTime();
```

Into a long variable (I want ms from epoch), the thing is (obviously) I can't convert it directly, as the variable `next` only contains information about the day of the week and the time of the alarm.

Do I need to add all the info that's missing on the date by hand? Or is there any method that does it?

I also tried to use

```
 AlarmManager m = (AlarmManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 long next=m.getNextAlarmClock().getTriggerTime();
```

but to no avail, as It gives me a nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 2):

[`getTriggerTime()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo.html#getTriggerTime()) returns a `long` not `Long`. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720992/what-is-the-difference-between-long-and-long-in-android-code.)

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
long nextAlarmTime =alarmManager.getNextAlarmClock().getTriggerTime();

Date nextAlarmDate = new Date(nextAlarmTime);
System.out.println(nextAlarmDate);
```

Here, the return value is the time at which the alarm is going to trigger. This value is UTC wall clock time in milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was a typing mistake, in my program I used long. Anyways, I tried again with your code, but it throws the following exception ``/com.example.almudena.mad_btv1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.almudena.mad_btv1, PID: 26198
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long android.app.AlarmManager$AlarmClockInfo.getTriggerTime()' on a null object reference``